# Change color of one LinearLayout to two colors by using canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-paint

I'm trying to change background color of one LinearLayout to two colors for some reasons like the following pic:

[image: two colors]

I'm writing this code but the problem this LinearLayout take third different color for the two parts like this pic:

[image: one color]

What is the problem in the logic of my code I don't know or I can not do something like that in Android?

Code:

```
c = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cell);
c.setBackgroundColor(getColor(container.get(0)));
c.setBackgroundColor(getColor(container.get(1)));
int width = c.getWidth(), height = c.getHeight();
if (width == 0 || height == 0) {
    width = 100;
    height = 100;
}
Bitmap bitmap;
try {

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(0, height);
path.lineTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(width, 0);
path.lineTo(0, height);
path.close();

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setColor(getColor(container.get(0)));
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

path = new Path();
path.moveTo(width, 0);
path.lineTo(width, height);
path.lineTo(0, height);
path.lineTo(width, 0);
path.close();

paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
paint.setColor(getColor(container.get(1)));
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the problem was in the way of parsing color in setColor method I replaced this one:

```
paint.setColor(getColor(container.get(1)));
```

by:

```
paint.setColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(),getColor(container.get(1)), null));
```

and everything is ok now.